# How to explicitly stop a scenario and continue with other scenarios in cucumber JVM

Tags: testing, groovy, bdd, cucumber-jvm

I am using Cucumber JVM with Groovy and using try catch block in assertions like:

```
try {
    assert response.status == 200
    tr.pass("Status is 200")
} catch(AssertionError err) {
    tr.fail(err.message)
}
```

Now, if somehow assertion fails then it will catch the exception and not stop the scenario at that time and start executing next step in same scenario. I have 2 choice:
1. after try catch I put my assertion again
2. Add some code in catch block which abort my scenario and proceed with next scenario.

I am preferring option 2. Please help me out.

Not tr.pass and tr.fail are user defined function to write status,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it is doing already if you do not use try catch in step definition. You could use assertion in step definition.

```
assertTrue(response.status == 200);
```

If it fails than stop scenario and skip other step (When,And and Then) and move on other scenario.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. We have thought of that solution but somehow in our framework it was not working. So we did some changes in framework and create a user defined function to handle all other scenarios including this.